# Turn off night light via the terminal

Tags: nightlight

I need to do this remotely on someone's computer using SSH, so would like to know if its possible via the terminal.

I did try to use X11 over SSH, but I think it would crash because the setting is in the video section.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with `gsettings`.
The key you are looking for is `night-light-enabled` which is in the `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color` schema.
The value can be either `true` or `false`.
To disable Night Light, set the value to false with the `set` sub-command as in the following.

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled false
```

You can confirm this change by then checking the key's value with the `get` command as follows.

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled
false
```